# Confusion in Creating Simple Neural Network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, machine-learning, neural-network

I was trying to create a Simple Neural Network through MATLAB (reference https://becominghuman.ai/making-a-simple-neural-network-2ea1de81ec20, although the author has coded in JavaScript, I wanted to do the same using MATLAB). I created my own MATLAB Live Script, but I am really confused as to my weights vector I created does not update. I am trying to add a learning rate of 0.20 to the weights(3) element, so as to make it reach 1 (I am trying 6 trials for training the network). I am new to using MATLAB and generally code in Python, so  if I the mistake I am making/the thing I am missing is kindly explained or what line of code is wrong, I would be grateful. Thanks a lot!

Here is my piece of code:-

```
inputs = [0 1 0 0]'
weights = [0 0 0 0]'
desiredresult = 1
disp('Neural Net Result')
res_net = evaluateNeuralNetwork(inputs, weights)
disp('Error')
evaluateNeuralNetError(1, res_net);
learn(inputs, weights)
train(6, inputs, weights)



function result = evaluateNeuralNetwork(inputVector, weightVector)
    result = 0;

    for i = 1:numel(inputVector)
        result = result + (inputVector(i) * weightVector(i));
    end
end

function res = evaluateNeuralNetError(desired, actual)
    res = desired - actual
end

    function learn(inputs, weights)
    learningRate = 0.20

         weights(3) = weights(3) + learningRate
end

function neuralNetResult = train(trials, inputs, weights)
    for i = 1:trials
        neuralNetResult = evaluateNeuralNetwork(inputs,weights)
        learn(inputs, weights)
    end
end
```

EDIT

Here is the updated (working code) as per accepted answer by Marouen:-

```
inputs = [0 1 0 0]'
weights = [0 0 0 0]'
desiredresult = 1
disp('Neural Net Result')
res_net = evaluateNeuralNetwork(inputs, weights)
disp('Error')
evaluateNeuralNetError(1, res_net);
learn(inputs, weights)
train(6, inputs, weights)



function result = evaluateNeuralNetwork(inputVector, weightVector)
    result = 0;

    for i = 1:numel(inputVector)
        result = result + (inputVector(i) * weightVector(i));
    end
end

function res = evaluateNeuralNetError(desired, actual)
    res = desired - actual
end

    function weights = learn(inputs, weights)
    learningRate = 0.20

         weights(3) = weights(3) + learningRate
end

function neuralNetResult = train(trials, inputs, weights)
    for i = 1:trials
        disp('Neural Network Result')
        neuralNetResult = evaluateNeuralNetwork(inputs,weights)
        weights = learn(inputs, weights)
        disp('Error')
        evaluateNeuralNetError(1, neuralNetResult)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you missed a loop in the `learn` function, double check with the original article.

```
function learn(inputs, weights)
    learningRate = 0.20

    for i =1:length(weights)
        if(inputs(i)> 0)
            weights(i) = weights(i) + learningRate
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT

You also have to update weights in the loop of `train` function

```
weights=learn(inputs, weights)
```

and add weights as output in learn function declaration

```
function weights=learn(inputs, weights)
```

Otherwise `weights` do not get updated. You can also declare `weights` as a global variable.

Comment: I left that loop because I was confused with the if condition. Can you please tell why is the if condition used here? I mean I can simply use the loop as I just want to increment weight for weights (3) , not for the entire vector.

Comment: I updated my answer. For this case the `if` statement is not important as you noticed.